# Сделать git push файла в репозитоий

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-branch, git-push

Такая ситуация: 
Залил в репозиторий файлы на github. Потом в репозитории удалил один из файлов. Теперь хочу файл с таким же именем(который удалил) залить в репозиторий снова.

В консоль Git я ввожу

```
Vit@Home MINGW64 ~
$ cd c:/xampp/htdocs/myproject

Vit@Home MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/myproject (master)
$ git add 1.php
fatal: pathspec '1.php' did not match any files

Vit@Home MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/myproject (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Запутался. Что делать чтобы залить этот файл на github?

Comment: Так он локально, в текущей рабочей копии, есть у вас?

Comment: ну он у меня в папке есть конечно на ноутбуке на xammp-e. Что нужно чтоб его залить на github в папку к другим файлам?

Comment: Если вы случайно удалили файл и не сделали push, то можно отменить локальные изменения "git reset --hard"

Comment: написал эту команду и у меня теперь вообще этот файл удалился с папки myproject

Comment: как теперь восстановить его?

Comment: уже восстановил с помощью git log --diff-filter=D --summary затем   
git checkout <commit_hash>~1 filename

Comment: Пишу $ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': *** выдаёт
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/***/***.git/'     хотя ж доступы правильные

Comment: Н-да... Попробуйте что ли документацию почитать.